# error while setting up vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to setup vagrant and when I do vagrant up, i get following error. I had never got this error before. But when i tried today, I am getting error.

```
GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.17) and guest (5.0.16) do not match.

Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
Downloading VirtualBox Guest Additions ISO from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.17/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.17.iso
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try again.

The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

I believe this is because below url is not accessible:
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.17/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.17.iso

Is there anyway to make vagrant not check this?

But I don't know how to resolve this issue. Any help would be of great helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install the [vagrant vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) and it will manage all this for you including the download of the correct version and the installation

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
$ vagrant up
```

If you do not want the plugin to make an update, add this in `Vagrantfile`

```
  # set auto_update to false, if you do NOT want to check the correct 
  # additions version when booting this machine
  config.vbguest.auto_update = false
```

As you noticed 5.0.17 does not exits from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/ so you can try to upgrade to 5.0.18 which exists from the available download

Comment: Tried but no success.  Same issue

Comment: Thanks mate. It helped :)